# How to serialize multiple types in Spring Redis Cache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-redis

The `RedisCacheManager` only takes a single RedisTemplate, which means it can only serialize a single type of object.

Since I have multiple types of object to be serialized, how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If your `CacheManager` is created by Java code. `new RedisTemplate()` should be used to support multiple types.
By default, `org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate` use `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` to convert Java object to bytes before store them in `Redis` server. 
It could support Java class implemented `java.io.Serializable` interface.

You can also specify other [Serializers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer), for example:

```
XStreamMarshaller xstream=new XStreamMarshaller();//org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.XStreamMarshaller
xstream.afterPropertiesSet();
//set serializer for all Redis type - convert object to XML string
redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new OxmSerializer(xstream, xstream));
//set serializer for Redis key type
//redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
//set serializer for Redis value type 
//redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new OxmSerializer(xstream, xstream));
```